# KendoUI dropdown depends on another dropdowns in kendo grid table

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo grid table that contains two columns of kendoDropDowList the main column and sub column. For example, 
The main Column is Category which is having 3 categories A,B,C. if I select category A , the second column should show 1,2,3 values, if I select B category it should show in second column 4,5,6 values. Last, if I select C category it should show 7,8,9 values. The user then can select any value from the list in the second column.  I know that my first kendoDropDownList will be

```
function categoryDropDownEditor (container, options) {
console.log(" field name :"+options.field);

                $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        autoBind: false,
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        filter: "contains",
                        change: onCategoryChange,

                        dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                dataType: "json",
                                url: "getAllCategories",
                            }// end read
                        }// end transport
                    }// end datasource

                    });
            }
```

and the function for onCategoryChange will be

```
   function onCategoryChange(e)
   {
         var value = this.value();
         alert("on change value "+value);
         // now here I don't know to set the kendowDropDownList datasource 
        //for the second column in the same row ... how to do that
   }
```

Comment: What editing mode is your grid using?  If inline or popup, look at this: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/cascading-dropdown-editors.  If in-cell...this is more complicated but I have done it and will try and write up an answer...but it will take me a bit.

Comment: it is inline mode , I have tried to use the given example . I have a problem in the second column , it shows me only one option not all options related to first column.

Comment: Can you wire up a (non)working example in the Kendo UI Dojo, with your remote transport calls replaced with local data OR with your remote calls replaced with Kendo Service calls(i.e. //demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Categories and //demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products)?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have followed carefully the example and it works well. Now I have small question why the brandId in ( cascadeFrom: "brandId" ) , should be the same name in    [ var input = $('<input id="brandId" name="brandId">');  ] and also should be the same in  [ dataValueField: "brandId" ]  in order to work perfect. I tried to change one of them the result is that the second column is listing all the values without considering values of column1.